# NetBeans runs a Java program with compile time errors

Tags: java, netbeans, compiler-errors, jit

The following Java program cannot compile due to errors in the else clause.

```
public class Temp1 {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    if (args.length == 0)
    {
        System.out.println("PASS");
    }
    else{
        COMPILEERROR
    }
}
```

}

Nevertheless, when run in NetBeans, after being notified of the errors and clicking "Run Anyway" the program runs and output "PASS". When the condition fails (when the args > 0), the program throws a RuntimeException:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable source code - not a statement
```

How does NetNeans run uncompilable code? Is it running an interpreter / JIT compiler or something like that?

Is this a new feature since I do not recall it in the past?

Comment: Presumably it removes the unreachable/uncompilable code and replaces it with a `throw`.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Thanks! I verified that you are correct and I credited you in my answer. If you'd like to get credit for your answer, please do so and I will delete my answer.

Comment: No problem. And that's quite alright, I took a WAG; you actually checked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

as @ElliottFrisch commented, NetBeans removes the unreachable/uncompilable code and replaces it with a throw

Here is the decompiled code:

```
/*
 * Decompiled with CFR 0_114.
 */
package temp1;

import java.io.PrintStream;

public class Temp1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        if (args.length != 0) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Uncompilable source code - not a statement");
        }
        System.out.println("PASS");
    }
}
```